# HTTP Post to curl syntax

Tags: curl

I have an HTTP Post (below) that I need to run as a curl command but can't seem to get it to work no matter what I try.  What should my curl syntax look like?

```
POST /ABRXMLSearch.asmx/ABRSearchByABN HTTP/1.1
Host: abr.business.gov.au
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

searchString=XXX&includeHistoricalDetails=N&authenticationGuid=YYY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl -d "searchString=XXX&includeHistoricalDetails=N&authenticationGuid=YYY" -X POST  https://example.com/ABRXMLSearch.asmx/ABRSearchByABN`

[See](https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58)